# How to remove multiple conda environments using one command line

Tags: anaconda, conda

I know that the following command can be used to remove **one** specific anaconda environment:

```
$ conda env remove -n env_name
```

But, is there any way I can specify multiple anaconda environment names in the above command line?

Answer (score 3):

According to the conda documentation, it doesn't seem like `conda remove` supports multiple envs, but a simple for loop would do the trick.

On Windows:

```
FOR %G in (env1 env2 env3) DO (conda remove -n %G --all --yes)
```

Note that if this is done from within a batch script, you might have to use `%%G` instead of `%G`

On Linux:

```
for env_name in env1 env2 env3; do conda remove -n $env_name --all --yes; done
```

Also note that the `--yes` option will remove the confirmation promt from `conda remove`, so be careful not to accidentally remove the wrong envs.